# How can I write this code more efficient?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, simplify

So one of the problems that were in the exam for me is to make this group of code more efficient with at least 1 line less command.
And I didn't know how to do it.The goal of this code is to get the 4 right bits of the first number,the left bits from the second number from the array (which its address is located in si) and then to merge those 8 bits- and to put the result in a 8 bit register.
0dh is the ASCII of enter,I need to make sure that enter isn't one of the chars that user had input,if it does 0 should replace it.(The array is an array of characters)
This is the code:

I thought maybe she just meant to get the line that doesn't effect the returned value to outside of the function but she told me that that's not what she meant so its wrong.

```
cmp [byte ptr si],0Dh
je LessThan4
mov al,[si]
shl al,4;(a)-first nibble
inc si
cmp [byte ptr si],0Dh
je LessThan4
mov dl,[si]
and dl,240;11110000b
shr dl,4;(b)-second nibble 
or al,dl;al=ab merging the nibbles
inc si
jmp Normal
LessThan4:
mov[byte ptr si],0
Normal:
ret
```

The excepted result is using 1 command,that will swap 2 commands in the current code.
Edit: Honestly I don't know why did I use this line: mov[byte ptr si],0
I don't need it,I need to put 0 instead of enter if there is enter. But this is happening alone because the function ends if there is an enter in the array,and 0 is what replacing the second nibble or both of the nibbles but I did need to make sure al is 0.
If this is what she meant im so embarrassed and tilted because I might not be able to get to the subject I want to learn next year in our class.): ): ): ): ):
I should have been able to see it pretty easily so that's really bad for me...

Comment: I don't quite understand the purpose of `cmp [si], 0dh; je LessThan4`.  How does that mesh with the question?  If you just want to merge the nibbles, try `mov ax, [word ptr si]; rol ax, 4`.  This leaves the result in al.

Comment: @fuz oh sorry I forgot to mention it. 0dh is the ASCII of enter,I need to make sure that the enter isn't one of the chars that user had input.(The array is an array of characters)

Comment: But what if the first number is 13?

Comment: @TheNiv in that case, what is the output supposed to be?

Comment: @RaymondChen I forgot to mention that if the first number is 13 it should just be a 0.I realized my mistake about it-needed to do xor al,al at the start of the code.

Comment: My point is it's not clear whether you have an array of numbers or an array of ASCII characters. It seems that you sometimes treat it as a number, and sometimes as a character. (That said, I think the answer the exam was looking for was to remove the `and dl,240`.)

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks.When I look back,I should have just asked myself what am I doing in each line and Im sure I could easily spot it.. Maybe it was anxiety or maybe I just wasn't focused but I guess I approach it the way I needed.

Comment: @RaymondChen Oh and about the array.It is an array of characters. But you can also treat it as an array of numbers because  in assembly each character is treated by its ASCII code  which is a number

Comment: True, but it's unusual for something to be treated as both a number *and* a character. Users do not think "I need to type a character whose ASCII code in hex has a the upper four bits equal to 5." Usually, you convert the character to a number by some human-meaningful algorithm.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because code review questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The expected result is using 1 command, that will swap 2 commands in the current code.

The `and dl, 11110000b` instruction before the `shr dl, 4` instruction is redundant. The shift right will by itself throw out the low 4 bits.

### There are a couple of things that I would like to draw your attention to.

- How the nibbles are combined

  > get the 4 right bits of the first number, the 4 left bits of the second number and then merge those 8 bits

  The logical way to present this combination of bits would be to keep those 4 right bits aka low nibble in the low nibble of the result, and to keep those 4 left bits aka high nibble in the high nibble of the result. Your code doesn't do it that way and neither do the other answers. Perhaps because they want to mimic what you've written.

  If the 1st number is in `AL` and the 2nd number is in `AH` then `and ax, 0F00Fh` will  mask away the unwanted bits and `or al, ah` will leave the combination in `AL`
- How 13 is replaced by 0

  > 0Dh is the ASCII of enter. I need to make sure that enter isn't one of the chars that user had input. If it does 0 should replace it.

  I think that you could be misinterpreting this "...0 should replace it."
  Probably this is DOS and input was terminated with <kbd>enter</kbd>, and so a carriage return (13) was appended to the inputted characters. What your teachers warns about is that the value 13 cannot become part of the result. You replace it with zero in the calculation *but not in memory*.

### If this is a one-time calculation

Returning a result in `AL` and keeping `SI` put.

```
    mov     ax, [si]
    cmp     al, 13
    jne     L1
    xor     ax, ax      ; Falling through shaves off an instruction
L1:
    cmp     ah, 13
    jne     L2
    xor     ah, ah
L2:
    and     ax, 0F00Fh
    or      al, ah
    ret
```

### If this has to be repeated for all characters in the string

Always returning a result in `AL` and having `SI` point at either the remaining characters or the terminating carriage return.

```
Again:
    mov     ax, [si]
    cmp     al, 13      ; If 1st byte is 13, then next byte is just garbage!
    je      CR1         ; ... so no further interpretation needed
    and     al, 0Fh
    inc     si
    cmp     ah, 13      ; If 2nd byte is 13, then result is based on 1st byte
    je      CR2         ; ... and that kind-of zero-replacement
    and     ah, 0F0h
    inc     si
    or      al, ah

    ...

    jmp     Again

CR1:
    xor     al, al
CR2:
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I appreciate the long answer. I understood some of the points you mentioned just after reading my code again, such as the enter replacements and some more stuff. Your answer is very clear though so thanks again,I learned something from this thats for sure.

Answer (score 3):

Try this then:

```
        lodsw                ; load ax from [si], then increment si twice
        cmp al, 0dh          ; was the first character a CR?
        jz enter1            ; if yes, abort
        cmp ah, 0dh          ; was the second character a CR?
        jz enter2            ; if yes, abort
        rol ax, 4            ; combine the digits in al and ah into al
        ret

enter1: dec si               ; return back to the first character
enter2: dec si               ; return back to the second character
        mov [byte ptr si], 0 ; terminate input with a NUL
        ret
```

This implementation uses 11 instructions instead of the 15 instruction of your implementation, saving 4 instructions.

Comment: Thanks. Eh,I guess rotate just disappeared from my mind... this isn't hard actually. ): I hope I can still get into the class I want because I really like to code more than some other people in my class but I didn't succeed in assembly because it was new for me I guess. Im not the worse but compared to the whole class i might be in the top 60% so idk..We learn C# too and I was way ahead from my class in it.Assembly may be a bigger percentage  of the requirements though.Anyways I have hope.

Comment: Your `lodsw` assumes the direction flag is clear.  You might need a `cld` instruction to ensure that it is.

Comment: @TheNiv To be fair, I wouldn't expect students to spot that `rol` can be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

> The goal of this code is to get the 4 right bits of the first number,the left bits from the second number from the array (which its address is located in si) and then to merge those 8 bits- and to put the result in a 8 bit register. 0dh is the ASCII of enter,I need to make sure that enter isn't one of the chars that user had input,if it does 0 should replace it.

The task doesn't say exactly what the combo should look like, so just bringing them together in any register should suffice.

`mov ax, [si]` loads `AL` with the 1st number and `AH` with the 2nd number.

The 4 right bits of the 1st number are in the low nibble (bits 3 to 0).
The 4 left bits of the 2nd number are in the high nibble (bits 7 to 4).

`ROR ax, 4` will rotate the low nibble of `AX` into bits 15-12, and shift the high nibble of `AX` down into bits 11-8. Now `AH` holds the combination of bits.

```
 mov ax, [si]
 cmp al, 13
 je  CR
 cmp ah, 13
 je  CR
 ror ax, 4            ; combine the digits in al and ah into al
 ret
CR:
 mov byte [si], 0
 ret
```

This has but 9 instructions.

Comment: Note that this overwrites the wrong byte if `al` is not CR but `ah` is.  It also leaves SI with the wrong value at the end.

Comment: @fuz Why would `SI` be important at the end. If anything having it at the start makes the most sense.

Comment: OPs takes great care to advance SI appropriately.  I can't say whether this is part of the requirements as OP didn't say, but I think it is.  Neverthless, your code is also wrong in that it overwrites the wrong byte if AL is nor CR but AH is.